# Google Analytics SDK for Android v2

Tags: android, events, google-analytics, tracking

I want to include Google Analytics in my android application, but I'm unable to see events in google analytic page. Here is my code:

analytic.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools"
           tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-00000000-0</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">50.0</string> </resources>
```

java code:

first version:

```
 Tracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).getDefaultTracker();
 tracker.sendEvent(category, action, label, value);
```

second version:

```
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).getTracker("UA-00000000-0").sendEvent(category, action, label, value);
```

but none of these works (I see in analytics page that screens are viewed, but I don't see any events in Engagemend->Events->Overview). Am I doing something wrong? I have a tracking id.

What are the differences between those two version of code?

Answer (score 0):

Got it: after I send an event, I have to call

```
GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
```